# Почему возвращает NULL в произвольном поле (ACF)?

Tags: php, wordpress

на WordPress пользуюсь ACF полями, и пытаюсь получить как внутри продукта, так и вне, изображение этого произвольного поля, но мне возвращает NULL

```
<?php 

$image = get_field('ikonka');
var_dump($image);
if( !empty($image) ): ?>

    <img src="<?php echo $image['url']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $image['alt']; ?>" />

<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$image = get_field('ikonka');
```

В таком исполнение вызов должен делаться внутри цикла, например:

```
<?php while( have_posts() ) : the_post() ?>
     <?php $image = get_field('ikonka'); ?>
<?php endwhile; ?>
```

Также можно попробовать, если вызов идет на странице

```
global $post;
$image = get_field('ikonka', $post->ID );
```

Также нужно помнить про ситуацию, если Вы используете WP_Query() перед get_field, то после выполнения WP_Query() сделать вызов wp_reset_query();